# CSS Positioning Bug

Tags: html, css

I am developing html websites. Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="width:100%;height:50px;z-index:1;"></div> 
        <div style="width:100px;height:50px;z-index:2;position:relative;top:-50px;"></div>
        <div style="width:10px;height:50px;z-index:3;position:relative;top:-100px;"></div>
     </body>
</html>
```

The code here is very simple. I intend to group the 3 elements into one line. However, the spaces under the element at their original position are reserved. How can I remove the white spaces under?

Comment: `* { margin : 0; padding : 0; }` ?

Comment: Also, your third div closing statement is missing a < if this is the actual code you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're using relative positioning. In order for relative positioning to work, the browser has to load the DOM first so it knows the original location of the element, it can then apply the positional values to move it, this means the document will not re-flow around the positioned elements hence your white space. The quickest fix is to wrap your div stack in a relative positioned `div`, then apply absolute positioning

```
<div style="position:relative">
        <div style="width:100%;height:50px;z-index:1;"></div> 
        <div style="width:100px;height:50px;z-index:2;position:absolute;top:-50px;"></div>
        <div style="width:100px;height:50px;z-index:2;position:absolute;top:-100px;">/div>
</div>
```

You'll have to play with the inner div positional values, but that should work for you. The wrapping div with relative position set makes the absolute positioning use that div as the parent, rather than the body element, so in your example it is not required, but in the real world, you'll probably want to do this.

However, i'd consider whether a `<ul>` elemnt would be more appropriate in this scenario

Comment: I am not familiar with the ul tag. What are the advantages of using ul element instead of div element? In addition, how to remove the dot in front of each li element?

Comment: `<ul>` is a list tag, it's used for making lists of elements, which if your stacking your `<div>`'s vertically, is roughly what your doing. The `<ul>` tag should tag some of the positioning trouble's away as the browser will render each element on top of next automatically. To remove the dot, just use `list-style-type` CSS

Comment: @SamuelCheung http://jsfiddle.net/ELbSt/ example if a simple UL for stacking your divs

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would try ul element.

Comment: @SamuelCheung I would avoid unsing a `ul` element as it's not a representation of a list which is the sematically correct use for a `ul` element. Take a look at the example in my answer - is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

`relative` positioning reserves the space where the element originally would have been placed. Use `position:absolute` instead. However, absolute positioning works differently. While relative takes coordinates "relative" to the element's original position, absolute takes coordinates relative to the parent<sup>*</sup> element's position.

<sup>*</sup>: The nearest ancestor with position other that static or if none is present, the body. In your case it would be the body.

Example:

```
<html>
    <body>
      <div style="position:relative">
        <div style="width:100%;height:50px;z-index:1;"></div> 
        <div style="width:100px;height:50px;z-index:2;position:absolute;top:0;"></div>
        <div style="width:10px;height:50px;z-index:3;position:absolute;top:0;"></div>
      </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Sidenote: avoid inline styles and your markup is broken - you are missing a `<`.

**[See the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cfhGt/)**